# Level Control System - Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink

As in the figure, my source is a step block. With the step block, I can set my final value to 60 - that is great because that is my set point. However, I cannot start my simulation at a different value than just 0, t=0.

[image: Simulink Figure]

I want to be able to start my simulation from let say y=54, t=0 like this:

[image: Required Result]

Comment: Why not?  The `Step` block has a parameter for the starting value just like it has one for the ending value.

Comment: It does but even if you set an initial value, it won't take it in the step block. I learned that simulink has a transfer fcn where you can set your initial value. So I was able to figure that one out..

Comment: Of course, you need to set the initial state of the PID integrator and of the plant correctly to reflect the new initial step value.

Comment: The Step Block has a "Step time" parameter allowing you to specify when the output of the block changes from the initial value to the final value. Can you use that?

Comment: I've tried every possible way in the step block but I don't think I saw anything about step time. It's preset to start from zero  ( I am not entirely sure), but if you're using a transfer function block as your plant, then you can choose a transfer fun block with initial values.